# How do you change the colors of the text when doing a Schema Compare in Visual Studio 2008 Database Edition?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, configuration, colors, color-scheme

I am trying to find out how to modify the `Colors/Fonts` used in the Schema Compare "`Object Definitions`" window that appears after a comparison is done between two databases.

The color scheme I have is unreadable, but I cannot seem to find the right settings in the `Tools/Options/Environment/Fonts` and `Colors` dialog.

Thanks for any help.

Jason

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help you...

[Fonts and Colors, Environment, Options Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw7t0545%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)